# Problemas com a inserção e recepção de valores do MySQL com CodeIgniter

Tags: php

Estou utilizando o framework de CodeIgniter, comecei meus estudos a uns dias. Estou enfrentando alguns problemas para a criação de um CRUD. Algumas delas é a conexão com o banco. Tento inserir valores na tabela, mas não vai, e ao inserir pelo terminal e printar no PHP fica assim:

[image: Foto do erro]

model_Conta.php:

```
class Model_conta extends CI_Model{
        public $id;
        public $nome;
        public $idade;
        public $profissao;

        public function conexao(){
            try{
                $conexao = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ListaContatos;charset=utf8", "joao", "");
                return $conexao;

                }catch(PDOException $erro){
                echo "Conexao falhou: ". $erro->getMessage();
            }
        }

        public function inserir($nome, $idade, $profissao){
            $PDO = Model_conta::conexao();
            $PDO->query("INSERT INTO contatos(nome, idade, profissao) VALUES ($nome, $idade, $profissao);");
        }

        public function retorna(){
            $PDO = Model_conta::conexao();
            $contatos = $PDO->query("select * from contatos");    
            foreach($contatos as $contato){
                print_r('<pre>');
                print_r($contato);
            }
        }
    }
```

Base.php:

```
public function cadastrar(){
    $nome = $this->input->post('nome');
    $idade = $this->input->post('idade');
    $profissao = $this->input->post('profissao');
    $this->load->model('Model_conta');
    $this->Model_conta->inserir($nome, $idade, $profissao);

}
public function retorna(){
    $this->load->model('Model_conta');
    $this->Model_conta->retorna();
}
```

Erros:

> Retorno da tabela com valores a mais;
>       Não está inserindo os valores no banco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo, você já começou totalmente errado. **Não** é para você criar uma conexão `PDO` dentro de um model!

Você tem que usar a conexão de banco de dados do CodeIgniter, para ver como que configura você pode ver neste link:

https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html

Para obter alguns exemplos de como se usa, você pode usar este link:

https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/examples.html

Toda a documentação sobre banco dados do codeigniter, se encotra nesse link:

https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/index.html

*** Você esta nomeando o Model de forma incorreta, você tem que usar `Nome_model` e não `Model_nome`.**